# optimize sum array array of objects by key in postgresql

Tags: arrays, postgresql, merge, sum, jsonb

I need a postgresql function that merge and sum (by key) 4 jsonb array of objects. Each jsonb can have 0 or multiple objects:

```
parameter 1: [ {"a": 1.0}, {"b": 2.5} ]
parameter 2: [ {"a": 1.0} ]
parameter 3: [ {"a": 1.0}, {"c": 2.5} ]
parameter 4: [ {"a": 1.0}, {"b": 2.5} ]
```

and the result expected is this:

```
[{"a": 4.0}, {"b": 5}, {"c": 2.5}]
```

I have a function that actually does that. But it's performance is very poor. I need to call it for each row. At this moment, with 1.4 millions of rows, the difference adding the function call is from 39 sec, to 2 min 30 sec. we expect to raise about more than 50 million of results, and that will be about 1 hour 40 min aprox.

I'm really new to postgresql and this is the best function I can do. I don't know if there is a more effective way to do this.

this is my actual function.

```
create or replace function join_and_sum(parameter1 jsonb, parameter2 jsonb, parameter3 jsonb, parameter4 jsonb) returns jsonb
    language plpgsql
as
$$
DECLARE
    column_jsonb            jsonb;
BEGIN

    select into column_jsonb jsonb_agg(p.jsonb_build_object)
    from (
             SELECT jsonb_build_object(key, SUM(value::float))
             FROM (
                      SELECT (JSONB_EACH_TEXT(j)).*
                      from jsonb_array_elements( parameter1 || parameter2 || parameter3 || parameter4) j
                  ) j
             group by j.key
         ) p;

    RETURN column_jsonb;

END;
$$;
```

thanks in advance

Comment: You will probably get a better answer if you provide the definition of the original table since it is not necessarily the case that you should use a function for this. There might be more efficient ways to write the query without involving a function.

Comment: Thanks @mats-kindahl, It is not really a table. we are populating a precalculated set of prices for all the combinations of: articles, margins, shipping costs and commisions of our database for a fast reading process in a webservice. We can have many prices  per article, including a price per article for every providers we have (with the same combination of margin, shipping costs and commisions). We were storing the providers prices in a json per article, and then combining with full joins. That's why we were trying to merge them in the precalculated table. Maybe we need to make other approach

Comment: Not entirely sure why you have the data outside your database, but you're probably better off actually storing it in the database system and then using that to compute and collect information. You should be able to do read that directly from the database for your webservice.

Comment: I think I did not explain myself correctly. The precalculated set is a table in our database. The problem is calculating the json inside that table. I was getting very good times until I started calculating the same for the providers prices inside the json so I tried to do it this way. By editing the question with all the query and process maybe I'm changing the content of my original question too much. Moreover, It is also difficult to write that part without exposing part of the business logic.